# "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" using fetch from Chrome

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

Objective: provide some basic data from Express JS to browser requests, all running locally on localhost.

When I connect to the URL (http://localhost/test) with the browser directly I see the data I'm trying to receive in the browser window.  However, when I execute the following code in a  tag in an HTML document I get "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and no data retrieved.

```
        fetch('http://localhost/test', {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Here's my Express code:

```
    app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
        res.header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:*"
        )
        res.json( {username: 'Joe'})
    });
```

I started without the "res.header" above but after many searches found that as a suggestion.  CURL and XMLHttpRequest both work fine.

Comment: Sounds like the server is returning an empty JSON response. Use the Network tab of the browser to see what's being returned.

Comment: I think you're right - it is returning an empty response.  What I can't figure out is why.  Both CURL and XMLHttpRequest can send a request and get a JSON response just fine.  For some reason fetch is unable to do this.  For now I'm just tossing fetch and using XMLHttpRequest.  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when the fetch is done? I can't think of a reason why fetch would fail when `XMLHttpRequest` succeeds.

Comment: Yeah it's the error in the title of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [something somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/12853922) recently. I think the problem might be that you are using a `no-cors` mode, which expects an opaque response. I'm no specialist in the matter but I suggest you check the link I shared.

I had a similar issue in vanilla JS and a REST API running on Azure (Function App). In my JS code, I removed the `no-cors` mode for the request; and in the REST API providing the response, I changed the allowed origins to `*` wildcard. Hope it's of any help.